# How to import .a static library based on C++ (GDAL) in swift

Tags: swift, xcode, gdal

GDAL is based on C++ and I created the library by running the scripts provided by the answer here [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/362137/building-gdal-for-ios) and also added the modulemap file, targeting the header files as described in the answer, but can't import the module at all.

I also tried to add the bridging header file for linking the header file of the library but, it should be in objective c but in my case it's in C++. I need GDAL for my project to convert the rasters data into coordinates.

Comment: I also tried other answers related to GDAL but all are answered long way from now and none of them are working.

Comment: you do need to add wrapper objective-c++ and bridging header for swift, 

we can’t help us without sample code, a can push to you OpenCV c++ sample project if you need